# What happened to Commander Wolffe after Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

As we all know:

- Gregor died fighting for what he believes in
- Rex got promoted to 'Commander' and fought in the Battle of Endor

But for some reasons, we never get to know what happened to the leader of Wolfpack. Does anyone know if Wolffe also fought with Rex during the Battle of Endor or if he settled down in some galaxy far far away?